# Implicit function theorem on 3 equations

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

Check for $x,y,z$ and $w$ if the equation system

$$3x + y-z+w^2 = 0$$

$$x-y+2z+w=0$$

$$2x+2y-3z+2w=0$$

can be solved respectively by the other three variables.

I tried to simplify the equation system $(III+II-I) \Longrightarrow w=0 \land w=3$ for example but i am not really sure if thats the right way.

I also had in mind to maybe calculate the roots of the equation system and then calculate the  Jacobian Matrix and then check if $a_{i,j} \neq 0$ for the roots to use the implicit function theorem. But i am really unsure so any tips are appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $\lor$ rather than $\land$? What you're doing sounds about right. Now you know $w$ must be $0$ or $3$ for the system to have any solutions, and so you can narrow down to two cases.

Comment: The next step is to investigate the rank of $\begin{pmatrix}3&1&-1\\1&-1&2\\2&2&-3\end{pmatrix}$ which will tell you about the nature of the solutions. As far as I can see, this is just a linear algebra question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system can be written as

$$\begin{pmatrix}3&1&-1\\1&-1&2\\2&2&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-w^2\\-w\\-2w\end{pmatrix}$$

As you've shown, $w=0\lor w=3$. So let us consider each of the cases:

$w\neq0\land w\neq3 \implies$ There are no solutions for $x,y,z$.

$w=3\implies$ Reducing $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}3&1&-1&-9\\1&-1&2&-3\\2&2&-3&-6\end{array}\right)$ using row reduction gives $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&\frac{1}{4}&-3\\0&1&\frac{-7}{4}&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right)$

$\implies \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{-7}{4}\\-1\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,,\,\,\,\lambda\in\mathbb R$

$w=0 \implies$ Reducing $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}3&1&-1&0\\1&-1&2&0\\2&2&-3&0\end{array}\right)$ using row reduction gives $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&\frac{1}{4}&0\\0&1&\frac{-7}{4}&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right)$

$\implies \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{-7}{4}\\-1\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,,\,\,\,\lambda\in\mathbb R$

---

Note that I was lazy and used a calculator to reduce the augmented matrix. If done algebraically, you'll get as the solution

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(w)\\f_2(w)\\f_3(w)\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{-7}{4}\\-1\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,,\,\,\,\lambda\in\mathbb R$$

in each case for some $f_1,f_2,f_3$.